# Whats the difference between 「睡眠不足」and 「寝不足」?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Is there is any difference between the words 「睡眠不足」(すいみんそく) and 「寝不足」(ねぶそく)?

Comment: I think they're the [same thing](https://hinative.com/ja/questions/6734900).

Comment: @Nanigashi Please don't post an answer in the comment section (unless you think this question is close-worthy). Short answers are okay as long as it's sufficient.

Comment: marcospins, can you edit your question to show what research you've done to try to find the answer yourself and why you remain uncertain about it? Otherwise, I think your question is likely to be closed. (@naruto – sorry! You're right, of course.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one from the comments is posting an answer: they mean the same thing.